# Show address bar (omnibox) in Chrome Android with javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

My web page is displayed with some html & css at the first place. Then upon user interaction, I initialize my application (sencha touch) which uses its own scrollable panel, not the browser's one.

So if I arrive on my website (not sencha touch app yet) with Chrome and scroll down, the Chrome address bar is hidden. Then I tap on a button for example to initialize the sencha touch app, this app will take fullscreen and scrolling will be handle by sencha. Now the address bar is still hidden and the web site will not have scroll up event so that Chrome can show the address bar again.

Can I programmatically show the address bar in Chrome with javascript?

Comment: Any luck? I've just encountered the same issue...

Comment: Your question seems to be Sencha specific, but [this hack](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24482865/1293492) might help you.